# Azure media service v3 - Create job with sas url is failing due to Access issue

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to create a asset from code, but i'm getting below error:
{
"error": {
"code": "Conflict",
"message": "The server received a 403 Forbidden error when accessing Azure Storage. Please check your permissions to the storage accounts linked to the media account.",
"details": [
{
"code": "AuthorizationFailure",
"message": "The server received a 403 Forbidden error when accessing Azure Storage. Please check your permissions to the storage accounts linked to the media account."
}
]
}
}
Also, I tried directly in portal with generated sas url, though I'm facing access issue, I can confirm AAD service principle has assigned "contributor" role, but still I get error.

Error:

The client 'xx' with object id 'xx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/assets/write' over scope '/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/itskssearchmediadev/assets/ignite-mp4-20220207-192422' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

What else permission do I need to provide?

[image]
[image]

Note: I also tried with my personal a/c which has full access, it works there.

Answer (score 3):

The [Storage Account Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-account-contributor) role permits management of storage accounts (e.g., creating and deleting storage accounts), but it does not permit access to data in the storage account.

To allow Media Services to write to the storage account, the Managed Identity must be granted a role that has [access to the storage account data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/concept-trusted-storage#tutorial), for example, [Storage Blob Data Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor).

Comment: Thanks, the issue got fixed after I tried to create the latest azure media service account with v3 enabled instead of enabling classic API and also with the role mentioned above. But now " i'm getting "Conflict", "message": "Unable to access the storage account () with the access token.", any idea why?

Comment: For the issue accessing the storage account, I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575201/13316065